Javascript Función comparar números para saber mayor, menor o iguales
Todo funciona bien hasta que pongo 3 números iguales.
Mi consulta es ¿cómo editar la función para que me de una respuesta de que todas son iguales o si dos son iguales y mayores?
function comparar(n1, n2, n3){
    if (n1 > n2 && n1> n3){
        console.log("el mayor es", n1);
     }else if (n1 > n2){
         console.log("el mayor es", n2);
     }else if (n2 > n3){
         console.log("el mayor es", n3);
     }
}


Hola Sasha, tu código tampoco funciona bien cuando n2 es el mayor, ni cuando n3 es el mayor. Diría que necesitas dedicarle unos minutos más al análisis de los casos.

Es para un ejercicio? Si no es así, podrías usar Math.max(n1,n2,n3)

Para obtener si los números son iguales, usa la comparación:
if (n1 === n2 && n2 === n3) {

para obtener si dos números son iguales o mayores puedes usar el método que comenta Pablo Lozano:
 Math.max(n1, n2, n3)

Por lo tanto este sería el método:
function comparar(n1, n2, n3) {
    if (n1 === n2 && n2 === n3) {
        console.log("Todos los números son iguales!");
    } else if (n1 === n2 || n1 === n3 || n2 === n3) {
        console.log("Dos números son iguales y mayores!", Math.max(n1, n2, n3));
    }
}


te paso una modificación que funciona:
    function comparar(n1, n2, n3) {
    if (n1 === n2 && n2 === n3) {
        console.log("Todos los números son iguales.");
    } else if (n1 === n2 && n1 > n3) {
        console.log("Los números 1 y 2 son iguales y mayores.");
    } else if (n1 === n3 && n1 > n2) {
        console.log("Los números 1 y 3 son iguales y mayores.");
    } else if (n2 === n3 && n2 > n1) {
        console.log("Los números 2 y 3 son iguales y mayores.");
    } else {
        // Si ningún caso se cumple, entonces ninguno es igual o dos son iguales y mayores
        console.log("Los números no son iguales o dos son iguales y mayores.");
    }
}

Espero que te sirva!
